# WDS's MDT DeploymentShare and REMINST replicated with DFS-R does not read WIM from local WDS

Tags: windows, deployment, wds, mdt-2012

I've read several guides on using DFS-R with WDS and MDT to replicate REMINST and DeploymentShare, and I have a particularly strange problem.

On the receiving server, after configuring WDS and mounting the DeploymentShare into MDT's DeploymentWorkbench, I also performed the following:

1) in .\Control\Bootstrap.ini, changed DeployRoot to \%wdsserver%\DeploymentShare$

2) Changed the UNC path at the root of the MDT Deployment Share in the DeploymentWorkbench to match that of the current server.

3) In Unattend.xml files located: .\Control**, modified the following value to match the current server: `<cpi:offlineImage catelog://HOST/`

I am able to boot and grab the LiteTouch PE image off the local WDS TFTP server, but the WIM files, the scripts, everything else is being pulled off the WDS server at the remote site (the original WDS server that was the source of the files within the DFS-R replicated folder).

What do I do in order to solve this problem?  I've grepped all the files below the `DeploymentShare` to look for instances of the hostname of the WDS server at the remote site (the source of the files), but I found none.

Here are the guides I referred to:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771324%28WS.10%29.aspx
- http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/12/16/wds-and-dfsr-love-at-first-sync.aspx
- http://oasysadmin.com/2011/11/03/copying-moving-and-replicating-the-mdt-2010-deployment-share/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bootstrap.ini is the control file that's injected into the boot wim. It is what controls which share the WinPE stage connects to. Did you remember to regenerate the boot file after changing bootstrap.ini?

Sidenote: You could do this a bit smarter, by using subnet filtering to dynamically set the correct values. That way you wouldn't need to maintain separate boot images per location. (Never tested this in WinPE though, so not sure it works)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the boot images needed to be regenerated!  I did not try that.  First I'll try the less invasive use of "Settings Priority" and "DefaultGateway" and "DeployRoot" in the boot.ini as described in [that last blog link](http://oasysadmin.com/2011/11/03/copying-moving-and-replicating-the-mdt-2010-deployment-share/).

Comment: I just realized that I'd have to modify `bootstrap.ini`, then regenerate the LiteTouch WIM PE images anyway, I assume.

Comment: Anytime you do an update to bootstrap.ini, you need to regenerate.
There's a ton of MDT videos over at channel9.msdn.com, the ones by Johan Arwidmark are really really good.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I simply watched: http://blogs.technet.com/b/danstolts/archive/2010/03/11/deploy-windows-7-the-easy-way-using-wds-mdt-and-aik-step-by-step-video.aspx and then doced config at our main site, used DFS-R to replicate the images (then decided to have it constantly replicated).  We're not big, and we're mostly doing this as a one time image.  I'm planning to roll out some additional layers for application deployment (namely chocolatey and a nuget server).

Comment: For future reference, note that if you performed the `Update Deployment Share` using MDT (2012) after modifying `bootstrap.ini`, you must also import those generated boot PE WIM images (`.\DeploymentShare\Boot\*`) into WDS (maybe removing the other images).